# Webview not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview, fragment

I have a webview in a tab activity fragment. However, my code only produces a blank page. The code does work in regular activities.

Main2Activity.java (Tab activity)

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpage1, container, false);
            return rootView;

        } else if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpage2, container, false);
            return rootView;

        } else {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpage3, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

subpage2.java

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getActivity());
final WebView browser = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpage1, container, false);

    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl("www.example.com");

    return v;
}
```

And fragment_subclass.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.subpage2">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize webview like this:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subpage1, container, false);
final WebView browser = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

try this: add `http` at front of the url

```
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
browser.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");   //add http at front  
browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

In manifest you have to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Done all that and no difference. Still a blank page unfortunately :/

Comment: try with different url...also see this answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560783/android-webview-do-not-load-in-fragment

Comment: Different url doesn't work. That answer had a similar problem but I don't have any other activity with a youtube video. I have checked the webview code countless of times and it works in other activities. I think something else is wrong but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by re-doing my tab fragments without unnecessary code from android studio. This time I did like in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LLd7qr9sA).