# Webview to Work In a Fragment

Tags: javascript, android-studio, android-fragments, webview

I have been looking around this site and Googling, but I'm afraid I am stuck. I just can't get a webview to work in my fragment. I've tried plenty of different code on here, but there must be something I am missing.

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="layout.GER1">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```html
package layout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import com.example.a1cmanny1.bmi.R;

public class GER1 extends Fragment {

    public WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ger1, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.nz/");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return v;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything in your code looks good. Whats the issue that you are facing?

Comment: The webview is just blank when I run it. It doesn't even try and load. Possibly I have missed something from the activity that enables the webview in the fragment?

Comment: I am also using the tabbed activity - swipe view template. I have the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

I have no idea why my initial code wasn't working, but I found this post:
[Webview not working in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042408/webview-not-working-in-fragment)
And copied the instructions in the video. After that, I added my above code and it works perfectly.

The tutorial I initially used for tabbed activities must have been incorrect.